# C# displaying query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to display my record from the SQL Server db can some help me with the function I need?

I am using C#, SQL Server 2005, the table is created with name and address etc.... etc, I insert it successfully is connected now I want to get the record from the table

Comment: Please clarify `display`. Would that be in a data grid? In a console window? Somewhere else entirely?

Comment: in windows form app data grid

Comment: You have provided very little information, not enough for anyone to be able to help. How are you accessing the database (what technology)? What is/are the table/s name/s? What data do you need to display?

Comment: @marc: its not issue put any name and any columns use the display query to display result in windows form not console.. display it in any thing i want jusy the basic method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is unclear but I think you need [something like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x64c23x%28VS.90%29.aspx). and [here](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/GridView-Control.aspx) how to connect a data grid view to a DB.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of options:

- straight ADO.NET - use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` to grab e.g. DataSets, or data readers, to handle your data
- use some kind of an ORM, like Linq-to-SQL, Entity Framework, NHibernate or something else, to turn your database rows and columns into .NET objects
- custom code - roll your own ORM or do something else to your liking

Due this vast array of options, it's really hard to know what you're looking for - which options are you interested in?? ADO.NET ? ORM (which one?) ??